# Install and load module with embeded _init__.py files

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I hate to ask a redundant question, but I am stuck and need help:

Let's say I have an example project structured like:

```
project/
    setup.py
    example/
        __init__.py
        prg.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_foo.py
```

`setup.py` looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='example', version='0.12c',
      description='Example Description',
      author='me', author_email='me@gmail.com',
      packages=['example'])
```

I am trying it install it to base anaconda (windows 10, python 3.6, conda version : 4.6.3)  using

```
python setup.py install
```

Everything seems fine:

```
Installed c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\example-0.12rc0-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for example==0.12rc0
Finished processing dependencies for example==0.12rc0
```

When I try and load my package in ipython:

```
import example
```

I get the following error:

```
In [1]: import example
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3ef45b82d40c> in <module>()
----> 1 import example

C:\workspace\git_clones\example\example\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from prg import object1, object2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prg'
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `.` to the import in `__init__.py`:

```
from .prg import object1, object2
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for a lot more information about relative imports.